# Work with datetime in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the problem with DateTime in C#.
I must create the system for promotion in my shopping.

1. First, I must get start promo time and end promo time
2. If the current time is on start and time user must pay another price.
3. If current date is Friday all product must use promo price

I think this:

```
public Class Product { 
    public DateTime StartPromoPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndPromoPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? PromoPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

if (DateTime.Now == StartPromoPrice && DateTime.Now > EndPromoPrice)
{
   // get promo price
}
else{
   // use standard price
}
```

How get all Friday from the years and can use promoprice!? 
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data in and the associated data out showing the various circumstances.

Comment: I don't understand your 2nd requirement: "If the current time is on start and time user must pay another price.". Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

Use [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911(v=vs.110).aspx) to find if it is Friday. Your logic might have some gaps as well, probably want >= and < as opposed to ==.

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
    || (DateTime.Now >= StartPromoPrice && DateTime.Now < EndPromoPrice))
{
    //get promo price
}

else
{
    //use standard price
}
```

Comment: I want to use dynimic DateTime. I create this if (db.Products.Where(x=>x.StartPromoPrice >= DateTime.Now) && db.Products.Where(x=>x.EndPromoPrice < DateTime.Now) but note work because return IQueryable from product!? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If current date is Friday all product must use promo price. You can try below to figure out if the current day is friday to avail promotion price.

```
DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if ((day == DayOfWeek.Friday)
{
  //Get Promo Price
}
```

Comment: He wants the condition to be true for more than one day . He has start and end time.